# Configure remote Weblogic managed server

Tags: weblogic12c

How to attach a stand alone weblogic server instance to an already existing domain?

- Machine A : Has Weblogic installed, SampleDomain configured with Admin server and one local managed server. I am able to start and stop this managed server.
- Machine B : Has weblogic installed. No Domain exists so far.

Now, I can use Pack and Unpack to include the other WLS instance on machine B to the domain at A. But, Without having to pack the domain to a remote machine, is there a way to simply attach the WLS on machine B to Domain at machine A.

Comment: Can both servers access the same domain directory? If so you can simply add a new server in the admin console. Or have you followed something like http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e14144/tasks.htm#WLDPU136 to set it up?

Comment: Again it requires Pack and Unpack of the domain from machine A. Can I avoid this and directly attach the WLS from machine B to the domain at machine A. I have tried nmEnroll(), but that did not work for me.